# Simple dice game C++ Having trouble switching players

Tags: c++

Hello I'm currently taking C++, and I'm a beginner. We had a choice to choose a dice game for our program. I chose a game that has the following rules:

Choose a number and roll the dice. You score a point every time you roll that number. When you roll that number, you get another turn. When that number is not rolled, the turn is over. Mark the tally for each time you roll the number.  First one to a certain score of 10 points wins.

I've been working on this for the past 2 days, and I'm so frustrated. Any help is greatly appreciated. We're using classes and constructors. My main issue is being able to go back and forth between the two players. I tried using a do while loop, but it didn't really help. Here's my code:

//Dice game

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Die
{
   private:
    int num;

   public:
    Die(); //Default constructor because it doesn't require arguments
    void roll();
    int getNum();
    void gameRules();
};

class Players
{
    private:
     int player1Num;
     int player2Num;

    public:
     void playerTurn();
};
void Die::gameRules()
{
    cout << "       ****Welocome to Madawi's Dice Game ****\n\n ";
    cout << "Here are the rules:\n\n ";
    cout << "This is a two player game, so grab a buddy!\n\n ";
    cout << "\t1.)Please choose a number from 1-6\n\n ";
    cout << "\t2.)Then roll the dice, if it lands on the number";

    cout << "\tyou chose, you get a point and go again\n\n ";
    cout << "\t3.)If you choose a number and it doesn't land on";

    cout << "\tthe number you chose,you don't recieve a point, ";
    cout << "\tand the second player goes\n\n ";
    cout << "\t4.)The first person to get to 5 points first wins!\n\n  ";
    cout << "ENJOY!!! Let's begin:\n\n ";
    }

Die::Die()
{
    num = 1; //Initialize so that the values start at one
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
}
void Die::roll()
{
    num = rand()%6 + 1;
}
int Die::getNum()
{
    return num;
}
void Players::playerTurn()
{
    Die die1;

    cout << "Hello player 1! Please choose a number from 1-6:\n";
    cin >> player1Num;

    cout << "You've chosen the number " << player1Num << endl;

     die1.roll(); //rolls the dice

     cout << die1.getNum() << endl; //displays number rolled


    if (player1Num == die1.getNum())
   {
     cout << "Good job player 1! You got the same number\n ";

     player1Points++; //Keeps track of player 1's score

     if(player1Points == 5)
    {
        cout << "Congratulations player 1 you've won the game!\n";
        cout << "Thanks for playing!\n ";
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Sorry the numbers didn't match up\n ";
    cout << "Player 2 its your turn\n ";

    cout << "Player 2 please choose a number ";
    cin >> player2Num;

    cout << "You've chosen the number " << player2Num << endl;

    die1.roll();
    cout << die1.getNum() << endl;

    if(player2Num == die1.getNum())
   {
    cout << "Good job player 2! You got the same number\n ";

    player2Points++; //Keeps track of player 2's points

    cout << "Player 2 its your turn again, please choose a number:\n ";
    cin >> player2Num;

    die1.roll();
    cout << die1.getNum() << endl;


   }
    if(player2Points == 5)
    {
        cout << "Congratulations player 1 you've won the game!\n";
        cout << "Thanks for playing!\n ";

    }

  }
}
int main()
{
    Die dice1;
    Players player1;
    Players player2;

    dice1.gameRules(); //Says the game rules

    player1.playerTurn(); //Player makes a selection

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck actually? Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problems.

Comment: I suggest factoring out the `gameRules` function out of the `Die` class since the rules apply to a game, and a `Die` can be used in many games (example: Monoply).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your architecture:

```
class Players
{
    private:
     int player1Num;
     int player2Num;

    public:
     void playerTurn();
};

int main()
{
    Die dice1;
    Players player1;
    Players player2;
//...
}
```

As defined above, you have 4 players.  Each `Players` class has 2 player numbers.

Decide.  Are you having a class containing all the players and controlling them or are you have a single player class and letting the `main` function control the players?

Answer (score 0):

You should create helper function `void makeTurn(int player);` And use it to make move for any player. It should contain do-while loop with rolling and scoring.

Pseudocode:

```
function makeTurn(playerNumber):
    display "Player " + playerNumber + "turn"
    do
        roll = rollDice();
        if (roll == playersChoice[playerNumber])
            display "You scored one point!"
            playersPoints[playerNumber]++;
        else
            display "Sorry, you have failed :("
            break //End the loop
    while true //Do infinitely (till break)
end function
```

Also, I don't see a reason for the Players class. Use an array for containing player scores and choices, then you can easily extend it to more players. If you meant it to be an ***instance*** of player, then you should just have score and choice fields, and the player move should be the makeMove function from the code I presented to you before, just using local fields instead of playersChoice and playersPoints arrays.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help! I got it to go from player 1 and go to player two, and also keep track of the amount of points for each player, but for some odd reason it only runs 4 times, and I have no idea why...

Comment: Post some code then :) Also, remember that the object oriented programming tends to resemble the real life relationships. There shouldn't be the 'Players' class, becouse they are not grouped by definition. On the other hand, Player class has a reason to exist, it can contain the fields and methods for a single player, then becoming grouped in array or vector :)